# Greedy calculator in C

Tags: c, calculator, cs50, greedy

I need to create a greedy calculator that accepts only `.25`, `.10`, `.5` and `.1`.
I need to print the minimum amount of coins needed to fulfil the change.

This is going on a loop and I can't see what to do to fix it. 
I am still learning, go easy on me :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    int coins = 0;
    int change;
    int i;
    do {
        change = get_float("How much change? ");
    }
    while (change <= 0); /* condition for acceptance*/

    int cents = round(change * 100);

    if (cents > 0) { /* run all whiles we get to 1c*/
        while ((cents - 25) >= 25) { /* run 25c */
            coins += 1;
        }

        while ((cents - 10) >= 10) { /* run  10c*/
            coins += 1;
        }

        while ((cents - 5) >= 5) { /* run  5c*/
            coins += 1;
        }
        while ((cents - 1) >= 1) { /* run  1c*/
            coins += 1;
        }
    } else { 
        printf("%d", coins);
    }
}
```

Comment: how do while loops end?

Comment: You aren't storing the results of your subtraction anywhere.  `cents` never changes as you increment your coins.

Comment: In `while ((cents-25) >= 25 )` (etc) why can't you give the last 25 cents? Did you mean `while (cents >= 25 )`? And as commented, it's missing `cents -= 25;`

Comment: @snowboly I think most of us 'go easy' on newcomers - provided they ask well-formulated questions. This is a sincere question, showing work and asking where the issue is. Those questions I like a lot, precisely because they show effort. You have some hints and answers now, but what I want to say is: keep this up! If you ask questions showing effort, SO tries very hard to be a welcoming place :).

Comment: @snowboly: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `change` is defined as an `int`, so the amount entered by the user is truncated before the computation even starts, producing an incorrect result.
- you do not update `cents` in any of the loops, so you get an infinite loop if any of these conditions is true.
- note that the conditions are incorrect: `(cents - 25) >= 25` is true if cents is greater or equal to 50.
- the test `if (cents > 0)` is incorrect. You would only print the number of coins if `cents <= 0`.
- the last loop is useless, the number of remaining cents is the number of pennies to count.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    float change;

    do {
        change = get_float("How much change? ");
    }
    while (change <= 0); /* condition for acceptance*/

    int cents = round(change * 100);  /* avoid rounding issues */
    int coins = 0;

    while (cents >= 25) { /* count quarters */
        cents -= 25;
        coins += 1;
    }
    while (cents >= 10) { /* count dimes */
        cents -= 10;
        coins += 1;
    }
    while (cents >= 5) { /* count nickels */
        cents -= 5;
        coins += 1;
    }
    count += cents;  /* count pennies */
    printf("%d\n", coins);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks! that now works. One question, the last line return 0. What is that for? if the change is 0.00001, it will not fulfuil any while and will return 0 due to int coins = 0. right??

Comment: @snowboly: `return 0;` has nothing to do with the change computed by the program, it is just the standard way for a C program to signal successful termination to the OS. The `main()` function has a return type of `int`. Since C99, the `return 0;` is implicit but I prefer keeping it explicit for consistency with the function prototype.

Comment: If the amount entered by the user is not a whole number of cents, the statement `cents = round(change * 100)` rounds the amount to the nearest number of cents. If the amount is `0.00001`, the amount will be rounded to `0` and the number of coins will be `0`.

Answer (score 0):

The `cents` variable never changes. `(cents - 25)` indeed returns the value of current cents minus 25, but you don't assign it to `cents` variable, so one of those 4 while loops will always be true.

There is also another probem: `get_float` function returns float while change variable is `int`, if the user were to enter a value less than 1, such as .5, it would be casted to 0 and prompt again and again until the user enters a value greater than 1. Also note you would probably get a wrong answer for any non-integer input.

Comment: thanks! I was not storing the cents number. I'm trying to fix the < 1 issue now.